# python embedding on Mac ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, c, macos, embed, cython

I'm currently unable to using the Cython embedding feature. The binary compiles fine and `otool -L embedded` returns the following results.

```
embedded:
        @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 3.6.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.60.2)

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1349.8.0)
```

This is the command I ran. Any thoughts on why this is not working? Cython using setup.py works fine when I want to create a Cython module, i.e. I'm able to import the Cython module in Python.

```
$ make

gcc -c embedded.c -I/Users/$USER/miniconda3/include/python3.6m -I/Users/$USER/miniconda3/include/python3.6m
gcc -o embedded embedded.o -L/Users/$USER/miniconda3/lib -L/Users/$USER/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin -lpython3.6m -ldl  -framework CoreFoundation  -Wl,-stack_size,1000000  -framework CoreFoundation

$ ./embedded

Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000000010f8113c0 (most recent call first):
[1]    32931 abort      ./embedded
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are basically trying to run a Python native code extension as a stand alone binary without the Python interpreter. This will never work.

Cython extension code produces extensions to the Python interpreter.

They are shared modules that can only be loaded within a running Python interpreter. They cannot be used as stand alone binaries.

If you want to make and distribute a stand alone binary of Python code with or without extensions, the interpreter will need to be bundled along with the code - see [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html).